Jenkins Pipeline - sshPut - Copy all files and folders
I want to copy all files and folders from current directory to Windows machine. Is there anyway to do this using sshPut command?
sshPut remote: remote, filterRegex: '.*', from: './', into: 'D:\DATA'
Tried this but did not work

Changed this line sshPut remote: remote,, from: '${env.WORKSPACE}/', into: '/D:/DATA' but this only copies entire directory. Tried also ${env.WORKSPACE}/* in from section but it gives me error.

sshPut remote: remote, from: '**/*', into: 'D:\\DATA'


Wildcard Pattern: Use from: '**/*' to match all files and directories recursively.
Windows Path: Use double backslashes (\\) for the Windows path to avoid escape character issues.


Hello. I have tried but it fails. At the end of console output in Jenkins is this error: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test-staging/**/* does not exist.
